# Form (submit) does not check for 'required' fields

Tags: javascript

I have a form with the form (submit) = addContact() function. This form has certain 'required' attributes. but when i click the add button, it does not show any error for the required fields being empty.

A workaround to this was that i defined a [form (submit) = isEmpty()] method to manually check these fields, but I do not understand why the first approach wouldn't work.

Before the workaround, i used 'required' as well as 'required="required" ' and 'required="true" '. None worked.

The problem:

```
<form (submit) = "addContact()" name="simpleForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "first_name" name = "first_name" class ="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn btn-success" value = "Add"> 
  </form>
```

After the workaround :

```
<form (submit) = "isEmpty()" name="simpleForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "first_name" name = "first_name" class ="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn btn-success" value = "Add"> 
  </form>
```

The isEmpty() Func:

```
isEmpty(){
    if(this.first_name ==null || this.last_name ==null || this.contact_no==null){
      alert("Please Fill all fields");
      return false;
    }else this.addContact();
   }
```

There are 3 fields in the form, i've just shown 1 to keep it short. They all are text fields only, nothing specific.

if I just use the addContact() on submit, it'll keep working through its logic even if the required fields are empty.

If I use the isEmpty(), it'll check it manually, and then give the alert if input is empty.

Comment: change `required="required"` to `required`

Comment: Following up Isaac's comment. required is a boolean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: I already tried that before, doesn't work.

Comment: try `(ngSubmit)=""` instead of `(submit)=""`

Comment: You can also try with `ng-required`, It will be more convinient

Comment: Neither of those two work.

Answer (score 0):

As the problem is tagged with javascript only, Providing a javascript solution.

Try to remove `(submit) = "addContact()"` with `action="javascript:addContact();"`

```
<form action="javascript:addContact();" name="simpleForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn btn-success" value="Add">
</form>
<script>
    function addContact() {
        alert("ok");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, i've defined the addContact in the contacts component. 
This is Angular, not just javascript. How would i go about this then?

Comment: I would prefer keeping html design and application logic separate, and doing it this way doesn't enforce that.